# data is not inserted if not exist using save()

Tags: php, yii

I am facing a problem with insert data using save(). using save() i successfully update data.but when the data is  not exist in database with perticular id  it not insert data.
controller :

```
public function actionContact()
  {
    //$profile=new Profile();
    $id=YII::$app->user->id;

    //$users=User::find()->where('id='.$id)->one();

    //$profiles=Profile::find()->where('user_id='.$id)->one();
    $this->layout="profile";
    $profile=$this->findModel1($id);
    $data=Yii::$app->request->post();

    if($data && $profile->validate()){

    $profile->mobile=Yii::$app->request->post('mobile');
    $profile->city=Yii::$app->request->post('city');
    $profile->zip=Yii::$app->request->post('zip');
    $profile->address=Yii::$app->request->post('zip');
    $profile->save();

    Yii::$app->session->setFlash("Contact-success", Yii::t("user", "Contact updated"));
    return $this->refresh();        
     }

    return $this->redirect(['/users/edit']);

  }
```

Any solution will highly appriciated.

Comment: If dadat not exists then replace $profile=$this->findModel1($id); with $profile=new findModel1();

Comment: Are you using same action for both update and save right? what is use of  $id if you explain more about this i can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$profile=$this->findModel1($id);
```

if there is no object found.

```
if(empty($profile)){
$profile = new Profile();
}
```

Comment: thanx for response . i tried this but not get success.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check this way.

```
$profile=$this->findModel1($id);
if($profile == null)
{
   $profile = new Profile();
}
```

In this i have checked if model is null then create new model object. and then it performs save.